Android. Transifex. Access new strings
I need to add key-value pairs in Transifex directly (not adding them to my strings.xml file), and then have MY server send the keys to the apps and web to be used via the TX SDK to get the appropriate translations.
iOS and Web work just nicely, but Android is basically using the resource Ids to find the appropriate translation, but in my case not having it defined in strings.xml , i have no resource Id to pass to getString(id: Int)
I tried the below, but it's returning 0.
int id = wrappedContext.getResources().getIdentifier(
                identifier,
                "string",
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
        );

//     where `wrappedContext` is the app context wrapped by Transifex

I looked at their SDK and there doesn't seem to be a direct method to pass the key of the string, AS A STRING, and get the value directly from their json files, basically bypassing the native resources.
Am I missing something or this can not be done on Android ?!?! It seems really absurd !
Cheers !
